# Get edited rows using dirtyflag in knockout

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

How can i create a dirtyflag in this situation?
Been looking for samples but nothing works for me
(I've just started learning knockout just a few days ago)

View:

```
`<h2>Knockout Table</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Choice Text</th>
            <th>Zero Tolerance Message</th>
            <th>Has SubChoice</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.choice.choice">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label data-bind="text: ChoiceText,visible:IsUsed"></label>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: ChoiceText, visible: !IsUsed">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label data-bind="text: ZeroToleranceMessage, visible: IsUsed"></label>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: ZeroToleranceMessage, visible: !IsUsed" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label data-bind="text: HasSubChoice, visible: IsUsed"></label>
                <select data-bind="foreach: $root.controlType, value: SubChoiceControlType,visible:!IsUsed">
                    <option data-bind="value: ControlTypeId, optionsValue: ControlTypeId, text: ControlType, attr: { title: ControlTypeId }"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type='submit' data-bind='click: choiceViewModel.save'>Submit</button>`
```

javascript:

```
 var ChoiceModel = function (choice) {
       var self = this;
       self.choice = ko.observableArray(choice);
       self.save = function () {
               //return value if not updated rows
          alert('Filter Changed');
       }

   }
   var choiceViewModel = new ChoiceModel([{
       ChoiceId: 92,
       CreatedBy: null,
       CreatedDate: null,
       ModifiedBy: null,
       ModifiedDate: null,
       ChoiceText: 'No',
       QuestionId: null,
       HasSubChoice: false,
       'SubChoiceLabel': null,
       Active: null,
       SubChoiceControlType: 1,
       ZeroTolerance: null,
       ZeroToleranceMessage: null,
       IsUsed: true
   }, {
       ChoiceId: 93,
       CreatedBy: null,
       CreatedDate: null,
       ModifiedBy: null,
       ModifiedDate: null,
       ChoiceText: 'Yes',
       QuestionId: null,
       HasSubChoice: true,
       'SubChoiceLabel': null,
       Active: null,
       SubChoiceControlType: 2,
       ZeroTolerance: null,
       ZeroToleranceMessage: null,
       IsUsed: true
   }, {
       ChoiceId: 628816,
       CreatedBy: null,
       CreatedDate: null,
       ModifiedBy: null,
       ModifiedDate: null,
       ChoiceText: 'Allen',
       QuestionId: null,
       HasSubChoice: false,
       'SubChoiceLabel': null,
       Active: null,
       SubChoiceControlType: 1,
       ZeroTolerance: null,
       ZeroToleranceMessage: 'sdasdasd',
       IsUsed: false
   }, {
       ChoiceId: 628817,
       CreatedBy: null,
       CreatedDate: null,
       ModifiedBy: null,
       ModifiedDate: null,
       ChoiceText: 'asdasda',
       QuestionId: null,
       HasSubChoice: false,
       'SubChoiceLabel': null,
       Active: null,
       SubChoiceControlType: 3,
       ZeroTolerance: null,
       ZeroToleranceMessage: 'sdasdasd',
       IsUsed: false
   }]);
   ko.applyBindings({
       choice: choiceViewModel

       ,
       controlType: [{
           ControlTypeId: 1,
           ControlType: 'Textbox'
       }, {
           ControlTypeId: 2,
           ControlType: 'CheckBox'
       }, {
           ControlTypeId: 3,
           ControlType: 'RadioButton (Yes/No)'
       }, {
           ControlTypeId: 4,
           ControlType: 'DropDownList'
       }]



   });
```

Here is the link the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/allen213/UHyk6/2/

Comment: What do you mean by "dirtyflag" ? What is the aim of the page ?

Comment: @Damien "DirtyFlag" is a flag that lets you know if a entry has been modified ,The aim if the page is it lets you update and send json that contains only the modified once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of Knockout is you don't have to worry about holding flags for this kind of purpose. You have an `ObservableArray` called `choice` which contains a bunch of `choices`. You can use the `subscribe` method to receive events when any of these observables change.

See the [KnockoutJS API](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) for observables, and scroll to the bottom of the page where it talks about *Explicitly subscribing to observables*.

For example, if you want to catch events when your ObservableArray of `choice` changes, you can use the code:

```
self.choice.subscribe(function(value) { /* Handle the change here. Use the value parameter to get the changes */ });
```

That subscribe method will get called when the array of choices is added to or removed from.

Now, if you want to receive events when the **individual choice properties** change, you'll need to turn those properties into `ko.observable` objects. Once you do that, you could then use the `subscribe` method in each of these objects to know when your `choice` list adds new objects.

You'll probably want to create a new object to define a `choice`, and in the object, you'll define the properties as observables. You can then define subscribe methods to handle the changes.

```
 choice = function() {

   this.choiceText = ko.observable(name);
   this.choiceText.subscribe(function(newValue) { /* The value of choiceText has changed to newValue */ });
   this.ZeroToleranceMessage = ko.observable("sdasdasd");
   this.ZeroToleranceMessage.subscribe(function(newValue) { /* Handle the change here */ });

 }
```

You can then put all of your `choice` objects into your `choices = ko.observableArray()` array.

Comment: what will i place inside in order to get the json of the changed value??

Comment: For instance, to subscribe when the `choiceText` observable value changes, you would have the following line: `this.choiceText.subscribe(function(newValue) {  });` The `newValue` parameter, in this case, will contain the new value for the `choiceText` observable. Read from this parameter, and handle the change however you need to.